# Using cd on a path alias also outputs the path

Tags: zsh

I wanted to create an alias for a directory so I don't have to keep typing it whenever I use cd or cp.

My .zshrc:

```
 setopt cdablevars
 export home=/mnt/c/Users/Home
```

But now whenever I use cd home/..., it also outputs "~home/...". Is there any way to get rid of this output?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature. You get also the directory printed if you do, say, a

```
cd -
```

or a `popd`. Whenever the directory you are changing to is not explicitly mentioned, it is printed so that you can sure that the shell is doing the right thing. Since `cdablevars` is nearly always used in interactive shells only, I don't see why this level of safety is a problem. If you really hate this output, you can redirect the stdout to /dev/null, for instance by

```
alias cd='cd >/dev/null'
```